# In need of dataset for fraudulent insurance claims

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, classification

I tried looking at all major sources but in vain. Is there any dataset of insurance claims with honest and false insurance claims? This is to be used to train and test a classification algorithm.

Comment: Did you got something? i am also looking for a similar dataset. Please do let me know if you was able to get something on this.

Comment: @kushagraGupta, if you like the question, you can upvote it and save it as a favourite (star); hopefully it would get more visibility and be more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

There is a data set about [credit card fraud](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) on Kaggle.

> The datasets contains transactions made by credit cards in September 2013 by european cardholders. This dataset presents transactions that occurred in two days, where we have 492 frauds out of 284,807 transactions. The dataset is highly unbalanced, the positive class (frauds) account for 0.172% of all transactions.

Source:

> The dataset has been collected and analysed during a research collaboration of Worldline and the Machine Learning Group of the Université Libre de Bruxelles on big data mining and fraud detection.